# C# check if object is of a type known only at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Why won't the following work?

```
if(!(obj is (DataGridView1.SortedColumn.ValueType)))
```

I get an error that a type is expected. Doesn't ValueType return a type?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ValueType` is not an actual class, right? It's a property that returns a `Type`. So to figure this out at runtime, you need to say:

```
if(!(DataGridView1.SortedColumn.ValueType.IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType())))
```

Answer (score 5):

Change your code to

```
if(obj.GetType() != DataGridView1.SortedColumn.ValueType)
```

**Edit** Updated code to fix typos

Comment: This is checking if `obj` is not of type `Type`, which I don't think is not what the OP wants.

Comment: `typeof(DataGridView1.SortedColumn.ValueType)` will return `Type`

Comment: I think you meant `obj.GetType()`, not `typeof(obj)`, which is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `ValueType` property is an instance of the `Type` class. It's not a type itself.

Try this:

```
if (!(obj.GetType() == DataGridView1.SortedColumn.ValueType))
```

However, this won't account if `obj` is a derived type, so if you need that, you'll have to get a little fancier.